# CSS Media Queries not loading correctly on IPhone 4

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

I am having problems with media queries not loading CSS or displaying the style correctly.

What I did was create a style480.css for my iPhone and style.css for normal.

I loaded

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

across my site so that it would work.

I set the css on the main site to read style 480 so I could stylize for the iphone. Everything looks great on my iphone, and of course it was just a boring list on my desktop.

After I got my style480 finished, I copied/pasted the css into a

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
{ 
    body {width:100%;}
}
```

in my style CSS.

Sounds pretty standard.

However it is not formatting correctly on my iPhone

The top nav menu (I used html 5 `<nav>`) is getting pushed to the left, a few of the lists are being floated when they shouldn't be.

It is like the iphone is mixing elements from in and outside the media query.

I have even tried putting the media query on top, putting it on bottom  and loading

```
-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.
```

Same thing, it is like it is mixing the css.

I even tried loading the css files separately on the HTML... exact same thing.

The only way I can get my iphone css to load correctly is if I set it as the main css for the page.  When I am loading 2 sets of css it is not working on the iphone (but it works on my laptop)

If I can find a way to view the css from the iphone I might be able to figure out what it is doing, but until them I am at a loss as to why it is not loading the CSS correctly

Answer (score 0):

> It is like the iphone is mixing elements from in and outside the media query.

Well, yes, that's how it works. The stuff outside the media query will be used, unless something *inside* the media query directly overrides it. You shouldn't pase all your code into the media query, just the stuff you want to adjust for that resolution.

A media query doesn't replace your main CSS file, it supplements it.